# how to show xml node in XSLT file based on passing an ID with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, xslt

I also have an xml file containing news headlines, there is a second xml containing full news stories. These xml files are linked by a unique story ID.

I am building a single web page which has 2 sections. In one section is a list of stories, which I can generate using XSLT and the headline xml file. I need to update the second section based on whichever link is clicked.

This is the xslt which generates the headline section

```
<xsl:for-each select="response/newsList/news">
    <div class="newsListItem">
      <h2><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h2>
      <p><xsl:value-of select="shortText" /></p>
      <p>
      <xsl:element name="a">
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        index.html?newsid=<xsl:value-of select="id"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="rel">
        <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
        removeContent(); displayXMLItem('newsItem','newsFullArticles.xml','articleFull.xsl'); return false;
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:text>More</xsl:text>
      </xsl:element>

      </p>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The xslt for the second section is

```
  <xsl:for-each select="response/newsList/news[id=?]">
    <div class="newsListItem">
      <h2>The Full Article</h2>
      <p><xsl:value-of select="text" /></p>
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

I understand that I need to somehow update the id=? to indicate which story I want to show but I can see how to do it. Unfortunately I can not use any server side language, it all has to be done in vanilla JavaScript.

The html page where I am calling everything is here

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
}
else
{
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

var displayXMLItem = function(container, xmlFileToParse, xslTemplate,itemIdentifier)
{
xml=loadXMLDoc(xmlFileToParse);
xsl=loadXMLDoc(xslTemplate);
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById(newsListContainer).innerHTML=ex;
  }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById(container).appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
var removeContent = function(){
document.getElementById('newsItem').innerHTML = "";
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Is what I am trying to do possible, without a server side language? Sorry if this isn't making sense, I have been banging my head against a brick wall for the past couple of hours so it seems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101349/addparameter-javascript-used-for-xslt-function-doesnt-work).